# Return documents that match a minimal number of words in the same sentence

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I need to return documents that match at least N words in the same sentence.

I split my documents per sentence and index each one as a separate value like so:

```
PUT /test_index/_doc/id1
    {
      "texts": [
"Your first step is the subject line.",
"You will have just seconds to gain the full attention of your reader."]
    }
```

and leave the position_increment_gap to the default 100.

Let say I need to match a minimum of 2 words.
I need to return the document if I search for the terms ("bla", "attention",  "reader") but not for ("bla", "subject", "reader"). "bla" is not in the document, "attention" and "reader" are on the same sentence, "subject" and "reader" are not.

The approach with a boolean should query and minimum_should_match does not work, as this query returns the document when it shouldn't:

```
"query" : {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {"term": {"texts": "subject"}},
              {"term": {"texts": "reader"}}
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 2
          }
      }
```

I need a way to mix proximity and minimum should match.
Is there a way to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

There is no provision to define **slop** amongst the clauses present with-in **should** which makes it evident that we can't have a query which can consider proximity amongst clauses in the should.

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[bool] query does not support [slop]",
        "line": 17,
        "col": 42
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[bool] query does not support [slop]",
    "line": 17,
    "col": 42
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

However, we can add min_should_match between different clauses having proximity search with-in them.

```
GET test-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
       {
         "match_phrase": {
           "texts": {
             "query": "Your step",
             "slop": 10
           }
         }
       },
       {
         "match_phrase": {
           "texts": {
             "query": "will have",
             "slop": 10
           }
         }
       }
       ],"minimum_should_match": 2
    }
  }
}
```